# Splitting strings as "|" and getting a total

Tags: java, regex

I have a file:

`2|BATH BE|19.00 20312|ORAN|1.42 04520|BOIL|1.78 20000|AV|0.98 2007|.C  312|1.78 0452|ONIOT BOILR H|2.98 2042009|.C |0.98`

I want to extract the numbers (19.00,1.42,1.78..) and get a summation out of it.

This is what I have done:

```
     public void checkTotal()
    {
        int total_price = 0;
        File file = new File(ItemUPC.txt");
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(file);
            while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
                String[] line = sc.nextLine().split("[|]");
                String price = line[2];
                total_price = total_price + Integer.parseInt(price);
        }
}
```

I am getting error as: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "19.00"

Its extracting only the first number it seems.
I want to get a sum of the numbers (19.00+1.42+0.98...likewise)

Any idea where I am getting wrong. Thanks :)

Comment: Integers don't have decimal points in them. Parse it as a double.

Comment: Andy post that as an answer maybe, it seems correct

Comment: `19.00 20312` is neither an `int` nor a `double`. You need to split it further on `\s+` and then parse the first part using `Double.parseDouble`. You can parse the second part using `Integer.parseInt` though.

Answer (score 1):

try  total_price = total_price + Double.parseDouble(price);